# kafka stream consumes very fast when starting and sudenly slows down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka topology that looks like this:

```
Sub-topology: 0
          |     Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input.topic])
          |       --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001
          |     Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001 (stores: [])
          |       --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000002
          |       <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
          |     Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000002 (stores: [])
          |       --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007
          |       <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001
          |     Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007 (stores: [])
          |       --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006
          |       <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000002
          |     Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006 (topic: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-repartition)
          |       <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000007
          |
          |   Sub-topology: 1
          |     Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000008 (topics: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-repartition])
          |       --> KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000005
          |     Processor: KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000005 (stores: [KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000004])
          |       --> KTABLE-MAPVALUES-0000000010
          |       <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000008
          |     Processor: KTABLE-MAPVALUES-0000000010 (stores: [])
          |       --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000011
          |       <-- KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000005
          |     Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000011 (stores: [])
          |       --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000012
          |       <-- KTABLE-MAPVALUES-0000000010
          |     Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000012 (topic: output.topic)
          |       <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000011
```

According to my metrics, a great deal of records are consumed in the minutes after starting up the application:

These are the records consumed from the input topic:

[image: Records consumed from input topic]

And here you can see the rate of records consumed per client_id:

[image]

I am using GCP to deploy the applications, and the cpu usage has spiked on starting the application, but it seems like I am hitting a bottleneck somewhere, as this cpu usage quickly descends:

[image]

Also, it doesn't seem to be the case where the application has consumed all available records in that time, as the source topic lag is around 350 million records and slowly descending during processing hours:
[image]

My configs are the default ones except for the `NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG` which is set to 4.

Any ideas on what could be causing this behaviour would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could this be the result of the application being started for the first time (or with  a different, 'new' application.id setting) and configured to read its input data from the very beginning?  If the app is pointed at an existing topic with lots of data, the app will be very busy after launch to crunch through all the historic data, and then become less busy once it has caught up with 'now' (newest data), at which point its load will be determined by the rate of new data being added to the topic.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because we don't change the consumer group for the application (same application id). Also when I look at the records lag metrics `sum(kafka_consumer_consumer_fetch_manager_metrics_records_lag) by (topic)` I can see a lag for the source topic at 350 million records that is reduced very little with hours of processing.